# Does the built-in function "highestbars" have bugs?

Tags: built-in, pine-script

Here's a simple test to demonstrate the issue:

```
//@version=4
study("Triangle",overlay=false)

length=input(title="Length",type=input.integer,defval=244)
long=input(title="Distance from 1 high",type=input.integer,defval=80)

x1=int(0)

x1:=-1*highestbars(length)>long?-1*highestbars(length):0
plot(x1,color=color.purple)
```

Here's the [unexpected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkbsU.png).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
h = highestbars(length)
x1:=-1*h>long?-1*h:0
```

Comment: Many thanks.It works.And thanks for the explanation to know why.